# Explain javascript code with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I navigated to a file while browsing the source code of a project. It is a javascript file and it contains the following:

```
var Tools = {};
... 
Tools.EMAIL_ADDR_PATTERN = /\w+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+?(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+/gim;
```

What type is the EMAIL_ADDR_PATTERN? Why is capitalised? How can be invoked?

This might be quite simple, however my js knowledge is very limited.

Comment: It's an email address pattern. What do you want from this?

Comment: why don't you just google regular expressions? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and a [small toy](http://regex101.com/).

Comment: [Any alpha numeric char with no length limit]@[Any alpha numeric char, _ and -  with no length limit].[Any char to a to z, A to Z with limited length between 2 and 6] in short. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters)

Comment: should be noted that the a-z A-Z is redundant, as it's matched case-insensitive (`/..../i`) anyway.

Comment: @amenthes quite ironic that the author used `\w` in the beginning but then went for `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` instead of `[\w-]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would use it:

```
var email = "name@somedomain.com";

if (email.match(Tools.EMAIL_ADDR_PATTERN)) {
  alert("this is an email");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is literally what it looks like. A [*regular expression literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is assigned to the variable `Tools.EMAIL_ADDR_PATTERN`. There's nothing special about capitalisation, it's likely a convention in the code to emulate constants.

Answer (score 1):

> > What type is the EMAIL_ADDR_PATTERN? Why is capitalised?

EMAIL_ADDR_PATTERN is the name of the property that the programmer has chosen. It can be anything.

> > How can be invoked?

Use the pattern in any method that accepts Regular Expression pattern such as:`string.match(Tools.EMAIL_ADDR_PATTERN)`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it's regular expression literal.

You can open a console in your favorite browser (press F12) and try for yourself:

```
> var r = /\w+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+?(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+/gim
> typeof(r)
"object"
> r.constructor
function RegExp() { [native code] }
> r.test("hello world")
false
> r.test("me@myself.com")
true
```

A REPL console is always a good friend. The Chrome one will even auto-complete method names so you can discover them more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Tools.EMAIL_ADDR_PATTERN just to validate the email string.

you can use like:

```
var flag = /\w+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+?(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+/gim.test('hello@world.com')
```

flag will be  **(boolean)true**